# Windows 8 App: Fixed button width: Failed to create a 'Windows.Foundation.Double' from the text '1in'?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, app-store

I'm creating a Windows 8 app for the app store using VS Express 2012 for Windows 8.  I want a button which is 1 inch wide, no matter the screen size and resolution.  I have this markup, which VS handles perfectly:

```
<Button Width="1in">Back</Button>
```

But when I try to launch my app in the simulator to test various tablet orientations, I get this:

```
WinRT information: Failed to create a 'Windows.Foundation.Double' from the text '1in'.
```

What's this about?  How do I fix it?  Is my scenario even doable, or do I have to resort to pixel-based width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Width property is a double and only valid values are numbers ex. 1, 3, 5.5 etc. representing device independent pixels. You can not use designations such as in, mm, cm or any others that could be used with CSS. If you want to make button to be exactly 1 inch wide you would have to use [screen dpi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayproperties.logicaldpi) and and use it to convert inches into DIPs.